# how to check the first 4 digits of a cell being leading zeros in excel macros?

Tags: excel, vba, leading-zero

I would like to build a module to meet the requirement
Read the nonce value in cell B7
Loop through 200 nonce values
Increment or decrement the nonce value by 1, 2, or 3.
Re-compute the Block Hash with the new nonce value
Check to see if the Block Hash has 4 leading zeros
If your Block Hash has 4 leading zeros,
Refrain from trying any more nonce values
Update an unused cell in the spreadsheet (cell H12 will do) with the words “Success as a Minor”

[image]

I tried to create 2 module which are assigned to increment and decrement button.
the code below is used for the increment:

```
Sub increment()

Dim i As Integer

Dim non As Integer

Dim hash As String

hash = Range("B9")

non = Range("B7")

If LEFT(hash,4) = "0000"

    Range("H12") = "Sucess as a Minor"

Else

    For i = 1 to 200

       non = non + 1

    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: What's the issue or error?

Comment: Your code looks strange to me: **a)** you declare `non` as String but that add something to it. **b)** You loop 200 times and add 1 instead of adding 200 all at once. **c)** you don't do anything with `non` (you for example don't write it back to "B7")

Comment: I just edited my code. I have a syntax error at the if function because I do not know how to check the leading zeros in the cell.

Comment: `hash = Range("B9").Text` ?